# BeautifulSoup.find_all does not return the class shown by "Inspect" under "div"

Tags: beautifulsoup

Goal: Query all the job records as a collection as part of job website scraping.

Steps: There are 100 job records and using "Inspect" in Google Chrome, it shows up as follows, when "Inspect"ing a single job record.

```
<div class="coveo-list-layout CoveoResult">
    <div class="coveo-result-frame item-wrap">
        <div class="content-main">
            <div class="coveo-result-cell content-wrap">
```

Problem: The following code does not return the count as 100, it is just 0. All of the above mentioned class were used in find_all, but it does not return 100 records. Attached a snip of the "Inspect" to show the class associated with a single record. Output of Inspect on a single job record:
[image: Output of Inspect on a single job record]

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
<Response [200]>
response.reason
'OK'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
cards = soup.find_all('div','content-list-layout CoveoResult')
len(cards)
0
cards = soup.find_all('div')
len(cards)
86
```

Code tried as follows: None of them work

```
cards = soup.find_all('div','content-list-layout CoveoResult')
cards = soup.find_all('div','content-list-layout')
cards = soup.find_all('div','coveo-result-frame item-wrap')
cards = soup.find_all('div','coveo-result-frame')
cards = soup.find_all('div','content-main')
cards = soup.find_all('div','coveo-result-cell content-wrap')    
cards = soup.find_all('div','coveo-result-cell')
```

Next Steps: Need help with finding the class associated with a single record. As a debug I have generated the output of "cards = soup.

Comment: Can you share the link if possbile!

Comment: https://jobs.intel.com/page/show/search-results#q=bangalore&t=Jobs&sort=relevancy&layout=table&numberOfResults=100&f:@countryfullname=[India]&f:@careerstage=[Experienced%20Hire,Intel%20Contract%20Employee,Entry%20Level]